# What is the right way of using "greater than", "less than" comparison on nullable integers in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
var _age: Int? = 0

public var isAdult: Boolean? = false
   get() = _age?.compareTo(18) >= 0
```

This still gives me a null-safety, compile error, but how can I use >, <, >= or <= in this matter?

Comment: Why don't you use non nullable Int for age? Is age at some point set to null?

Comment: I need nullable Int here for some reason.

Comment: The answer from @sergey below is correct and is a good solution.  Can you review it and if good, accept it.  If not, then please leave additional comments.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
var age : Int? = 0

public val isAdult : Boolean?
    get() = age?.let { it >= 18 }
```

The other solution would be using delegates:

```
var age : Int by Delegates.notNull()
public val isAdult : Boolean
    get () = age >= 18
```

So if you try to get age or check isAdult before age was actually assigned then you'll get exception instead of null.

Anyway I believe age = 0 is some kind magic that one day may lead to issue (even prod issue).

Answer (score 11):

Kotlin could sure use an extension function on `Int` for this, but until they do:

```
fun Int?.isGreaterThan(other: Int?) =
    this != null && other != null && this > other

fun Int?.isLessThan(other: Int?) =
    this != null && other != null && this < other
```

My methods returns `false`, not `null` if either operand is `null`. That makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

A generic and flexible solution would be:

```
infix fun <T : Comparable<T>> T?.isGreaterThan(other: T?): Boolean? =
    if (this != null && other != null) this > other else null

infix fun <T : Comparable<T>> T?.isGreaterThanOrEqual(other: T?): Boolean? =
    if (this != null && other != null) this >= other else null

infix fun <T : Comparable<T>> T?.isLessThan(other: T?): Boolean? =
    if (this != null && other != null) this < other else null

infix fun <T : Comparable<T>> T?.isLessThanOrEqual(other: T?): Boolean? =
    if (this != null && other != null) this <= other else null
```

Depending on your needs, you could use it as:

```
public var isAdult: Boolean? = false
    get() = _age isGreaterThanOrEqual 18
```

or:

```
public var isAdult: Boolean = false
    get() = _age isGreaterThanOrEqual 18 == true
```

Edit: Now available in [kotlin-lib](https://github.com/marco-eckstein/kotlin-lib).

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly use the built-in function [compareValue](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-values.html):

```
fun <T : Comparable<*>> compareValues(a: T?, b: T?): Int
```

```
public var isAdult: Boolean = false
   get() = compareValues(_age, 18) >= 0
```

or

```
public var isAdult: Boolean = false
   get() = compareValues(18, _age) <= 0
```

Note however that *null is considered less than any value*, which may suit your case, but may lead to undesired behavior in other cases. E.g., think of `var grantMinorsDiscount`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the null coalescing operator to convert from nullable Int? to non-nullable Int:

```
var age: Int? = 0

public var isAdult: Boolean? = null
   get() = if(age == null) null else (age ?: 0 >= 18)
```

Comment: This answer checks for null twice which is not necessary. By virtue of the first check the compiler knows `age` is not nullable in the else block.

Answer (score 0):

Also can try this:

```
var position = 100

    mArrayList?.let {

                if (it.size > 0 && position >= 0 ) 
                     return true

            }
```