# How to use less than < or greater > than in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How to use **less than (<)** or **greater than (>)** operator in kotlin?

I have checked `comparedTo(other: Int?)` function, but it only returns `Int?`.

```
class Adapter{
     private var mNewsCategories: List<NewsCategory>? = null
     //......
     val isAnything=  this.mNewsCategories?.size?.compareTo(0))
     //......
 }
```

The `val isAnything` returns another `Int?`. Actually, I need a `Boolean` variable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just use `< 0` or `> 0`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth what would `null < 0` evaluate to?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/29223898/9130109

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - What does the OP *want* it to evaluate to?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Don't know, but I wonder how adding `> 0` would work semantically with `null` values, since that's how I understood your suggestion.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth If it is `Int?` then there is a possibility of null, so we can't use `< or >` directly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It’s not possible to use `>` on nullable types. If you consider `null` to map to the size `0`, i.e. empty size, you can do:

```
val isAnything = (this.mNewsCategories?.size? ?: 0) > 0
```

While this will fix your problem, you should consider using `isNotEmpty` instead:

```
val isAnything = this.mNewsCategories?.isNotEmpty() ?: false
```

The Elvis Operator is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48254829/8073652).

Comment: Thanks for the precious answer. Can you explain elvis operator do, it will help lot of others .

Comment: See this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/48254829/8073652

Comment: Though, when checking for empty lists using `isNotEmpty` is probably easier than comparing to 0

Comment: That's probably true